# how can I display the text in an ordered list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, animation

Could someone please check my code? Thank you

Here is the fiddle site if you want to test:
http://jsfiddle.net/66QYr/

I would like to have the first 3 text to appear on the left (vertically) 
and then the next 3 text appear on the right (vertically)
then the next 2 text appear on the lower right bottom (vertically) 
and the last 2 text appear on the lower left bottom (vertically)

http://i197.photobucket.com/albums/aa253/tintingerri/Test/pic001.png

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>tintin</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <style type="text/css">


        #tintin{
        position: relative;
        top: 211px;
        left: 12px;
        font-size:14pt;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-family: Calibri;
        color:red;
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);
        opacity:0;}


        .image{
        height:350px;
        width: 855px;}


    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">



        var txt=['text1','text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6', 'text7', 'text8', 'text9', 'text10'], init=0,i=0,k=0,speed=20,el;



        var loopCount=1000;
        var j=0;
        //var padd = 20; //set this to an approriate increment
        function fade(){
        init==0?i++:i--;
        el.filters?el.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+i+')':el.style.opacity=i/100;
        el.firstChild.nodeValue=txt[k];
        if(i==100)init=1;
        if(i==0) {init=0;k++;j++;
        el.style.paddingLeft=20*k;
        }
        if(k==txt.length)k=0;
        if (j<loopCount) setTimeout('fade()',speed);
        }
        window.onload=function(){
        el=document.getElementById('tintin');
        fade();
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="tintin">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="image" style="background-image:url('pic007s.jpg')">;



            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You should create a <div> for each of those areas and use CSS to style their positions like this. Javascript plays a small role in this problem. Check this plugin http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

Comment: @eduardocereto: so js is not possible here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems you're trying to solve here:

1. Positioning the text in the appropriate places
2. Getting them to fade in

## Step One

The first problem can be solved with some simple CSS. Start out with a container:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}

<div id="container"></div>
```

The width and height can be anything, but you do have to tell it *something*. We're going to be putting our text in this container, but then use `position:absolute`. This will take them out of the normal document flow, and collapse the container if we have told it an explicit height.

The next step is the text. You're going to want four divs, with the text inside as paragraphs:

```
<div class="text" id="text1">
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
    <p>text 3</p>
</div>
```

Do this for each of the four blocks of text that you want to have. Use the same class name on each one, but give each their own, unique ID (`text2`, `text3`, etc.).

Finally, just use (as I said earlier) absolute positioning to place them where you'd like:

```
.text { position:absolute; }
#text1 { top:0;  left:0; }
#text2 { top:0; right:0; }
```

...and so on. When you're done, you should have something that looks like this:

[image: four absolutely positioned divs]

## Step Two

Fading elements in requires animation. You kind of have a basic animation function, but I suggest you read [Robert Penner's article](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/penner_chapter7_tweening.pdf) on tweening and animation. It was written for ActionScript, but the exact same principles apply.

For now, here's a good general-purpose JavaScript method that will take an element and fade it in:

```
function fadeIn(totalTime, elem, after) {
    var cos = Math.cos,
        PI = Math.PI,
        startTime = +new Date(),
        endTime = startTime + totalTime,
        timer;

    elem.style.opacity = 0;
    elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';

    timer = setInterval(function () {
        var currentTime = +new Date();
        currentTime = currentTime > endTime ? 1 : (currentTime - startTime) / totalTime;

        var distance = (1 - cos(currentTime * PI)) / 2;
        elem.style.opacity = distance;
        elem.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + distance * 100 + ')';

        if (currentTime === 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            if (after) {
                after();
            }
        }
    }, 40);
}
```

You tell this function how long you want the animation to last (in *milliseconds*), and you can also give it a function to execute when the fading is done (if you want; it's not necessary).

If I understood your question correctly, you want all the texts to start invisible, and then fade in, one at a time, clockwise from the top. We can make them invisible with CSS, but then if the user has JS disabled, the page will appear blank. So you need to first "get" all of the elements (either with some kind of `getByClass` function or with four different calls to `getElementById`) and set their opacity to 0.

So you can make the first group of texts fade in by doing the following:

```
var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
fadeIn(1000, text1);
```

The problem is, by doing this, there's no way to tell when to start the next animation. So we need to make a function, with the help of closures, to help keep track of things (this assumes that you've already gotten the elements in JS and made them invisible):

```
var tracker = (function () {
    var texts = [text1, text2, text3, text4],
        i = 0;

    return function () {
        var text = texts[i];
        if (text) {
            fadeIn(1000, text, tracker);
            i += 1;
        }
    };
}());
```

This function cycles through each element and fades it in when the previous one is done. (It's okay if the code doesn't make a lot of sense; closures are tricky things.)

[Here is the final result, in JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqWCQ/) Good luck.